# Python - Using the "except" after "try", as an "else" part for "try"

Tags: python, try-catch

I'm trying to understand (and could not find a definitive answer), whether it's considered good practice to use the "except" part of try-except, as a sort of "else" part.

EDIT - in order to try and be more clear:

Let's say I have 2 variables to test and I only "need" one of them as the answer (like if-else). Each of them would raise an exception if it fails. I try the first and it failed. Is it good practice to use the "except" section to continue the code with the second variable and set it as the chosen one, or should I only use the "except" part to handle the exception, and then do some other code (outside the "except" scope) to also test the second one?

---

Original:

That is - to write some code to the except, which is more then just a small except handle or print. More like a block of a few lines of code that would only happen if an the except is thrown, similar to an "else" statement. That is, in contrary to using the except just as a part to specifically handle the thrown exception and it's consequences.

Example -

```
try: perform-this-thing...

     perform-some-code

except:
     exception-raised-so-do-this-code...
     code
     code
     code
```

If that's not considered good practice - what is a more correct way to do what I seek?

Thank you all.

Comment: Now this isn't the "good" way. You should try to use if statements.

Comment: If that code makes only sense when an exception is raised then it *is* your exception handling code and obviously it should go there.

Comment: Let's say I have 2 variables to test and I only "need" one of them as the answer (like if-else). Each of them would raise an exception if it fails.
I try the first and it failed. Is it good practice to use the "except" section to continue the code with the second variable and set it as the chosen one, or should I only use the "except" part to handle the exception, and then do some other code (outside the "except" scope) to also test the second one?

Comment: @OronW Can you update your question with that example? It will be easier to understand what you mean.

Comment: Sure. I've edited my question. Hope it would make it more clear

Comment: @OronW I meant if you could provide that text example as code, like you did in your original question. Something that can actually be run, i.e. a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Exception handling is the process of responding to programming errors which disrupt the normal flow of program execution. The emphasis should be here on "*disrupt the normal flow*".

Use an exception handler to recover from such a programming error but don't mask real programming errors. Especially be careful with a wildcard exception handler and use it with extreme caution.

I'd argue that testing two variables and continuing with one of them if it is set is normal business logic and should be covered in an `if`-`else` statement as this is your normal flow.

If you can do this test only with a test for an exception then I'd say you can wrap the individual variable tests in a `try`-`except` and if unavoidable use nested exception handling but I'd advise against nested exception handling as it makes the code ugly and unmaintainable (nested would be here testing for the second variable in the `except` of the first).

Then if none of them is set that would cause an exception as this would disrupt the normal flow.

```
try:
    # Try to obtain variable 1
except ErrorObtainingVariable1
    # Log...
try:
    # Try to obtain variable 2
except ErrorObtainingVariable2
    # Log...
# Check to use variable 1 or 2
# If none set raise exception
```

(PS: There's also an optional `else` part of a `try`-`except` which follows all except clauses and is executed if no exception is raised. You could use this to avoid obtaining the second variable if obtaining the first variable was successful. See [the Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html) for more information.)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. If I understand you correctly - you advise to only use the except for managing the exception. Using your method, I would have to manage 2 different variables, and then **always** test them **both** to see which didn't raise exception, and use it as my result. This feels a bit long for such a "simple" test of "if the first raises an exception - use the other". Am I missing something? or is this just the more correct way to do it, even if it's a bit longer?  Thanks again

Comment: The general rule should be to avoid putting too much business logic into a exception handler, _correct_. But Python does offer control flow mechanisms with exception handling and in your use case that's what you want to do. So again, try to avoid using it as an `else` except in special use cases. Definitely avoid using a broad `except`. I personally don't feel the above solution is very long, it might be verbose but it's maintainable. If you're looking for something more elegant I think @Gabip solution is great (except for the broad `except`).

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer to use the following approach to prevent *indentation hell*:

```
# create an auxiliary function to choose the valid variable
def choose_variable(*vars):
    default_value = -1 # you can change it or remove it if you the default return value is None
    for v in vars:
        try:
            # check your var here
            return v
        except:
            continue
    return default_value
```

and then use it in your code:

```
chosen_value = choose_variable(v1,v2,v3)
print(f"The chosen value is {chosen_value}")
```

Comment: This is a great implementation! (in my opinion).
Since this doesn't really answer my general question for this thread, I can't choose it to be the answer, as I am looking for a more general practice in code writing. However, I think I will definitely use this form as part of my arsenal

Comment: I thought that your question was wether this is a good practice or not and I replied that IMO, this is not, because it would cause your code to be less readable because of indentation hell. Did I misunderstand your question?

Comment: My question was regarding the correct practice of a single try-except, in terms of good coding.
I was trying to understand, as my first sentence - whether it's considered good practice to use the "except" part to run some code that would only run in case of exception (or should I run it outside the except scope).
I think my example might have been a bit confusing so I've edit it, but the question did not involve indentation, or multiple/nested try-except. However, again, I think your approach is very elegant and I will choose it if no other general solution will be suggested. Thanks again!

Comment: @OronW You ask whether it's good practice "to run code that would only run in case of an exception" inside an `except` suite. Well, *by definition* that's where it should be. Where else could it possibly be placed? Anyway I encourage you to update your question with a specific example because I have the impression that people are speculating about what you're asking for and thus not providing accurate answers. It will help you receive an answer that is suited to your specific problem.

Comment: I understand that my description could have been understood differently then intended, but I was trying to be as general as I could. The point was to understand what type on content should I put in the except - to only handle the exception itself (write to log file, print to screen etc.) and then do more code logic, or can/should I write more logic inside the except. I feel @yvesonline answered my question so I've selected that answer.
I also think that Gabip implementation is very good and I would definitely use it in the future. Thank you all very much for your time spent answring here

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, these two forms of use of the try-except block are exactly the same if the use case is very simple. Something like this:

```
try:

    var1 = var + 1
    print(var1)

except:

    print(var)

    try:

        var1 = var + float(1)
        print(var1)

    except:

        print(var)

print('\n')
```

This version is equivalent to the first version of the try-except block

```
try:
    var1 = var + 1
    print(var1)

except:

    print(var)


try:

    var1 = var + float(1)
    print(var1)

except:

    print(var)

print('\n')
```

But depending on the effect that you're trying to achieve, the code can look differently, and have different results. Like this:

```
try:
    var1 = var + '1'
    print(var1)

except:

    print(var)


try:

    var1 = var + float(1)
    print(var1)

except:

    print(var)

print('\n')
```

This third version will have a different result than the second version.

Another way to write the code would be this, which is simplified.

```
try:
    var1 = var + '1'
    print(var1)

except:

    try:

        var1 = var + float(1)
        print(var1)

    except:

        print(var)
```

And this version is not the same as the first version of the try-except block.

When the code is executed, there will be different results.

```
15
15


15
15


151
15


151
```

Try-except blocks can become very complex and you have to choose the best version for your specific use case.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm trying to avoid nested try-except, and if I'll use the non-nested version, then even if the first try is successful - it will be writing over by the second try (assuming it's also successful). My goal is to test the first and use it if possible. I'll test the second only if the first failed.

Comment: Yes, I agree. Try-except  constructs usually need a lot of attention. I am happy that my answer helped!

Comment: I agree that the first version is the most easy to use,  but the first try-except block  can't  overwrite the second  try-except block. Anyway, this is indeed complicated, as you see. What I meant to say is that the non-nested version seems easier to use.